# Reopen path or connect two paths that are closed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs5

I have created two paths, but I want to change how the ends look.  How can I reopen the path at the bottom and continue drawing.

I tried adding a new anchor with the pen tool, but I couldn't understand how to join the two stems together at the end.

The easiest way for me to draw the shape I want is to do it separately, but because that didn't work I tried adding another anchor and dragging it out where I needed it to be.

Is there a way to easily join these paths?  I think Pathfinder might be the way, but I'm not entirely sure the best way to use it to achieve what I want.

[image: Two paths]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I achieved this was to **create two new anchors** and then **drag them on top of the anchors** from the adjacent path.

Then I used **Pathfinder → Unite**.

This meant they connected where I wanted them to.  Then I could add new anchors with the pen tool and drag them about.